# While loop stops at two iterations and the print procedure does not work

Tags: c, while-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to add books of type "llist" (the second struct) to a dynamic liste of books, each has the *information part* of type "infoL" (the first struct) and the *nxt* to point the following list node;

llist ajouterEnTete(args) allows to add a new node to the start of the liste
whereas void afficherListe(args) should print out the liste to the console.

I have two issues with this code:
(1)the while loop does not iterate as many times as i set the variable "nbrl", it always iterates twice and the process freezes.
(2)the afficherListe(ma_listeLivre) does not work unless i apply to only one node, so if i enter more than one, the process is stuck at adding a new node to the start of the liste. ( screenshot of the console is included)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char aut[30];
} infoL;


typedef struct listeLivre listeLivre;
struct listeLivre
{
    infoL info;
    struct listeLivre *nxt;
};

typedef listeLivre* llist;

llist ajouterEnTete(llist teteL, infoL newInfo)
{
    /* On crée un nouvel élément */
   llist node = malloc(sizeof(llist));

   node->info=newInfo;
   node->nxt=teteL;


   // element* nouvelElement = malloc(sizeof(element));

    /* On assigne la valeur au nouvel élément */
    //nouvelElement->val = valeur;

    /* On assigne l'adresse de l'élément suivant au nouvel élément */
    //nouvelElement->nxt = liste;

    /* On retourne la nouvelle liste, i.e. le pointeur sur le premier élément */
    return node;
}
void afficherListe(llist tetel)
{
    llist tmp = NULL;
   tmp= tetel;
    /* Tant que l'on n'est pas au bout de la liste */
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        /* On affiche */
        printf("ce qui doit etre afficher the id is %d ++ the author is %s +++ \n", tmp->info.id, tmp->info.aut);
        /* On avance d'une case */
        tmp = tmp->nxt;
    }
}
int main()
{
    /* Déclarons 3 listes chaînées de façons différentes mais équivalentes */
    llist ma_listeLivre = NULL;
    infoL LvrAjout;
        int nbrl;
        int i=1;
        printf("how many books ? *****\n ");
        scanf("%d", &nbrl);
        printf("le nbr de livre %d ***\n ", nbrl);
    //for (int i=0; i<nbrl; i++)
     //  {
while (i<=nbrl)
{
        printf("entrer le id\n ");
        scanf("%d", &LvrAjout.id);
        printf("entrer l auteur\n ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(LvrAjout.aut);
        printf("ce que j'ai ajouté %d  +++ %s ++++ \n",  LvrAjout.id, LvrAjout.aut  );
        ma_listeLivre = ajouterEnTete(ma_listeLivre, LvrAjout);
       //afficherListe(ma_listeLivre);
       //printf("%d \n", ma_listeLivre);
fflush(stdout);
        i=i+1;
}
afficherListe(ma_listeLivre);


   // return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In trying out your program, the main issue I found which most likely is the crux of your issue was the allocation of memory for your structure.

```
llist node = malloc(sizeof(llist));
```

As is, this bit of code is only going to allocate memory for the size of the pointer and not the size of the structure and probably give you undefined behavior.  Most likely, with the definitions as noted, one would want a statement such as the following.

```
llist node = malloc(sizeof(struct listeLivre));
```

With that in mind, and in order to get the program to compile, I did just a bit of refactoring.  Following is the refactored code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char aut[30];
} infoL;

typedef struct listeLivre listeLivre;

struct listeLivre
{
    infoL info;
    struct listeLivre *nxt;
};

typedef listeLivre* llist;

llist ajouterEnTete(llist teteL, infoL newInfo)
{
    /* On crée un nouvel élément */
    llist node = malloc(sizeof(struct listeLivre)); /* Needed to use the structure size and not the pointer */

    node->info=newInfo;
    node->nxt=teteL;

    // element* nouvelElement = malloc(sizeof(element));

    /* On assigne la valeur au nouvel élément */
    //nouvelElement->val = valeur;

    /* On assigne l'adresse de l'élément suivant au nouvel élément */
    //nouvelElement->nxt = liste;

    /* On retourne la nouvelle liste, i.e. le pointeur sur le premier élément */
    return node;
}
void afficherListe(llist tetel)
{
    llist tmp = NULL;
    tmp = tetel;
    /* Tant que l'on n'est pas au bout de la liste */
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        /* On affiche */
        printf("What should be displayed the id is %d ++ the author is %s +++ \n", tmp->info.id, tmp->info.aut);
        /* On avance d'une case */
        tmp = tmp->nxt;
    }
}
int main()
{
    /* Déclarons 3 listes chaînées de façons différentes mais équivalentes */
    llist ma_listeLivre = NULL;
    infoL LvrAjout;
    int nbrl = 0;
    int i = 1;
    printf("How many books ? *****: ");
    scanf("%d", &nbrl);
    printf("The number of books %d ***\n\n", nbrl);
    //for (int i=0; i<nbrl; i++)
    //  {
    while (i<=nbrl)
    {
        printf("Enter the id and author: ");            /* Compiler had issues with the gets function so used tweaked version of scanf */
        scanf("%d %[^\n]", &LvrAjout.id, LvrAjout.aut);
        printf("What I added %d  +++ %s ++++ \n",  LvrAjout.id, LvrAjout.aut  );
        ma_listeLivre = ajouterEnTete(ma_listeLivre, LvrAjout);
        //afficherListe(ma_listeLivre);
        //printf("%d \n", ma_listeLivre);
        fflush(stdout);
        i=i+1;
    }

    afficherListe(ma_listeLivre);

    return 0;
}
```

This is virtually your code with the change in the memory allocation, some translation to English mainly for my benefit, and revising the input using scanf for both the ID and author (I couldn't get the "gets" function to work).

With that following is some sample terminal output.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Books/bin/Release$ ./Books 
How many books ? *****: 3
The number of books 3 ***

Enter the id and author: 1 ee cummings
What I added 1  +++ ee cummings ++++ 
Enter the id and author: 2 John Smith
What I added 2  +++ John Smith ++++ 
Enter the id and author: 3 George Orwell
What I added 3  +++ George Orwell ++++ 
What should be displayed the id is 3 ++ the author is George Orwell +++ 
What should be displayed the id is 2 ++ the author is John Smith +++ 
What should be displayed the id is 1 ++ the author is ee cummings +++
```

One quirk I did notice is that listing function starts the list with the last book entry working its way back to the first book.  But it does produce a valid listing.

Try out these refactored tweaks and see if it meets the spirit of your project.